# Beating the compiler with a simple program finding the longest collatz sequence

Tags: performance, c, assembly, collatz-sequence, x86

I found [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40354978/why-does-c-code-for-testing-the-collatz-conjecture-run-faster-than-hand-writte) in Stackoverflow asking why his/her assembly program isn't faster than the C++ program. In his/her assembly program I saw the lines `mov rbx, 2; xor rdx, rdx; div rbx`, and I didn't even read further. Anyway the question was interesting enough for me to write an assembly program to see how much I can beat the compiler.

The program is a simple bruteforce solution to [problem 14 of Project Euler](https://projecteuler.net/problem=14).

The algorithm used in both the C and assembly version is the same; no algorithmic optimization was done.

This is the result in `rdtscp` cycles, which has a constant tick on my CPU. The first output number is the result of the function with input 10,000,000.

```
/* gcc */
8400511   c 1,710,915,921
8400511 asm 1,656,971,166
8400511   c 1,707,514,184
8400511 asm 1,653,252,527
8400511   c 1,702,896,033
8400511 asm 1,652,814,196

/* clang */
8400511   c 2,011,935,915
8400511 asm 1,655,126,396
8400511   c 2,009,606,165
8400511 asm 1,649,501,254
8400511   c 2,016,743,666
8400511 asm 1,653,020,407
```

My assembly version has a marginal win against `gcc` and quite a visible gap with `clang`. The assembly output by each compiler can be seen [here](https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/b88EjYzb4).

##### lcs_c.c

```
#include <inttypes.h>

static unsigned bsfq(uint64_t a) {
#if LONG_MAX == UINT64_MAX
    return __builtin_ctzl(a);
#else
    return __builtin_ctzll(a);
#endif
}

uint64_t lcs_c(uint64_t n) {
    uint64_t Mn;
    unsigned Mc = 1;
    do {
        unsigned c = 1;
        uint64_t n_ = n;
        for (;;) {
            unsigned c_ = bsfq(n_);
            n_ >>= c_;
            c += c_;
            if (n_ == 1) {
                break;
            }
            n_ = n_ * 3 + 1;
            ++c;
        }
        if (c > Mc) {
            Mc = c;
            Mn = n;
        }
    } while (--n > 0);
    return Mn;
}
```

##### lcs_asm.s

```
%define n rdi
%define n_ rsi
%define Mc r8d
%define c edx

    align 16
global lcs_asm
lcs_asm:
    mov Mc, 1
    jmp L0
    align 16
L0:
    mov c, 1
    mov n_, n
    jmp L1
    align 16
L1:
    bsf rcx, n_
    shr n_, cl
    cmp n_, 1
    je next
    lea n_, [n_ + n_ * 2 + 1]
    lea c, [c + ecx + 1]
    jmp L1
    align 16
next:
    add c, ecx
    cmp c, Mc
    ja L2
    dec n
    jz end
    jmp L0
    align 16
L2:
    mov Mc, c
    mov rax, n
    dec n
    jz end
    jmp L0
    align 16
end:
    ret
```

##### main.c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <locale.h>
#include <inttypes.h>

extern uint64_t lcs_c(uint64_t);
extern __attribute__((sysv_abi)) uint64_t lcs_asm(uint64_t);

static uint64_t rdtscp() {
    unsigned _;
    return __builtin_ia32_rdtscp(&_);
}

static void test(const char *id, uint64_t (*lcs)(uint64_t), uint64_t lim) {
    uint64_t c = rdtscp();
    uint64_t Mn = lcs(lim);
    c = rdtscp() - c;
    printf("%"PRIu64"%4s %'"PRIu64"\n", Mn, id, c);
}

int main() {
    setlocale(LC_NUMERIC, "");
    uint64_t lim = 1e7;
    for (int i = 0; i < 3; ++i) {
        test("c", lcs_c, lim);
        test("asm", lcs_asm, lim);
    }
}
```

##### build.sh

```
#!/bin/sh -x

C="gcc"
O="-O3 -march=tigerlake"
$C -c $O lcs_c.c
nasm -felf64 lcs_asm.s
$C $O -or main.c lcs_c.o lcs_asm.o
rm *.o
```

Comment: In the future it might be better to ask a follow up question rather than editing the current question.

Comment: Please refrain from adding updated code in your question to incorporate feedback from answers, doing so goes against the Question + Answer style of Code Review. This is not a forum where you should keep the most updated version in your question. Please see [What should I do when someone answers my question?](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers) as well as  [_what you may and may not do after receiving answers_](http://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1765).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I rewrote your assembly code a bit. I leave it to you if this results in any better performance.

- I reduced the number of branches. You had 2 in your inner loop, my code uses 1.
- I also inverted the conditional branch near the bottom and removed some code that was repeating itself. Again reducing branches.
- The few remaining branch targets are still paragraph aligned but I replaced the 'jump-over the nops' by the [recommended sequence of multi-byte nop](https://www.google.be/url?esrc=s&q=&rct=j&sa=U&url=https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43991155/what-does-nop-dword-ptr-raxrax-x64-assembly-instruction-do&ved=2ahUKEwim4oqFuez1AhWDt6QKHSbkBNIQFnoECAgQAg&usg=AOvVaw1Pm0UCS1lfqVznN_5fm399).

```
    align 16
lcs_asm:
    mov r8d, 1                         ; 6
    mov edx, 1                         ; 5
    mov rsi, rdi                       ; 3
    jmp L2                             ; 2
L1: lea rsi, [rsi + rsi * 2 + 1]       ; 5
    lea edx, [edx + ecx + 1]           ; 5
    db  66h, 0Fh, 1Fh, 44h, 00h, 00h   ; jmp L2 : align 16 -> 66 nop word ptr [rax + rax * 1 + 0]
L2: bsf rcx, rsi
    shr rsi, cl
    cmp rsi, 1
    jne L1
    add edx, ecx
    cmp edx, r8d
    jna L3
    mov r8d, edx
    mov rax, rdi
    db  66h, 0Fh, 1Fh, 44h, 00h, 00h   ; jmp L3 : align 16 -> 66 nop word ptr [rax + rax * 1 + 0]
L3: dec rdi
    mov edx, 1
    mov rsi, rdi
    jnz L2
    ret
```

The entire code fits in 78 bytes.

Comment: Your code is the fastest and the smallest. I just changed `bsr` to `tzcnt` to get a small boost.

Answer (score 2):

### 2-jump loop

The loop pattern of this loop could be changed to a 1-jump loop:

> ```
> L1:
>     bsf rcx, n_
>     shr n_, cl
>     cmp n_, 1
>     je next
>     lea n_, [n_ + n_ * 2 + 1]
>     lea c, [c + ecx + 1]
>     jmp L1
> ```

Move the part that exits from the loop to the bottom, the other part to the top, and then you have a loop with only one branch in it and no `jmp`, at the cost of having to enter the loop in the middle, but that's easy in assembly and there was already a `jmp` to enter the loop anyway to skip the alignment padding.

Like this:

```
    jmp Lentry
    align 16
L1:
    lea n_, [n_ + n_ * 2 + 1]
    lea c, [c + ecx + 1]
Lentry:
    bsf rcx, n_
    shr n_, cl
    cmp n_, 1
    jne L1
    .. etc
```

### Avoid 32-bit address in `lea`

In 64-bit code, `lea` with a 32-bit address costs an extra address-size-override prefix. `lea` with a 64-bit address and a 32-bit destination doesn't need any prefixes and has *almost* the same semantics, except that some specific encodings have different meanings. The differences are not important here, so you may as well use `lea` with a 32-bit destination but a 64-bit address, that's the cheapest option for x64. The cost in this case should be insignificant and quite possibly unmeasurable, it's not as if `lea` with an address-size-override is slower in and of itself, but it costs an extra byte and that may have decoding and µop cache implications.

### Depending on the target processor and context, maybe avoid 3-component `lea`

On some processors, notably Intel processors older than Ice Lake, 3-component `lea` has a latency of 3 cycles while the other forms have a latency of 1 cycle. That makes it have a higher latency than a 2-component `lea` plus a separate `add`, though that costs 2 µops and the 3-component `lea` still only costs one.

Depending on the context, the latency or the µop count may be more important. In this case I think the latency is important, because it's part of a loop-carried dependency, so replacing `lea n_, [n_ + n_ * 2 + 1]` with `lea n_, [n_ + n_ * 2] \ inc n_` may help. LLVM-MCA doesn't think so, but [uiCA](https://uica.uops.info/) agreed and it's more accurate than LLVM-MCA, so it looks promising.

Intel Ice Lake and AMD processors would either prefer the original 3-component `lea` or at least don't penalize it.

### Consider using `tzcnt` instead of `bsf`

For Intel processors that shouldn't make any difference, but `bsf` is typically somewhat slow on AMD processors, while `tzcnt` is fast on all processors that support it (it is very widely supported at this point) and *especially* on AMD processors which tend to implement it even more efficiently than Intel. So using `tzcnt` is neither a win nor a loss on Intel processors, but a significant win on AMD processors.

Comment: `tzcnt` was actually *very slightly* faster on my machine (Tigerlake). I'm suspecting maybe `bsf` having an output dependency is making a tiny difference even though there is a bit of gap between executing `bsf`. AFAIK `tzcnt` should be free from output dependency on Tigerlake, but still `gcc` zeros the output before `tzcnt` as if there is. `clang` doesn't do this. Both were given `march=tigerlake`.

Comment: Whether or not `gcc` is mis-optimizing in this case, I've seen somewhere that some CPU's have hardware *bugs* that `tzcnt`/`lzcnt`/`popcnt` has a false dependency on the output register, so I didn't feel comfortable using `tzcnt`. Well, while writing this comment I realized `bsf` has an output dependency by default, so I don't seem to lose anything using `tzcnt` anyway, apart from a bit of portability.

Comment: @xiver77 yea actually I discovered that bug (well, maybe, it's hard to tell and hopefully Intel engineers knew even if they didn't come out and warn us) or at least [noticed it pretty early](https://stackoverflow.com/q/21390165/555045)

Comment: I appended a revised version on the OP applying some of your suggested optimizations. It is about 0.15% faster than the original. About 0.1% is from switching to `tzcnt`, and about 0.05% is from rearranging the loop. These are very rough numbers, but I ran enough tests to be sure that a certain version is at least slightly faster than another.

Comment: I couldn't change the 3-component `lea` to `lea` + `inc` because that resulted to be more than 20% slower on my machine. I don't have a spare machine right now to test if the result is different, but I'm now wondering what would be a better *generic* choice, 3-component `lea` vs `lea` + `inc`.

Comment: Also putting `Lentry` without alignment runs slower on my machine. See what I did in the final version. I'm not sure if it applies to all `x86` machines, but at least mine seems to be very sensitive to instruction alignment of jump targets in heavy loops.

Comment: @xiver77 OK that align in the middle of the loop body helping is unexpected to me especially since there's now still a `jmp` in the loop as well, so it's not even saving a jump. It would have made more sense that it helped if it was a manual align by using a multi-byte nop or redundant prefixes or something similarly extreme, but this is pretty weird.

Comment: BTW if your processor is Tiger Lake then it has the same fast 3-component `lea` that was introduced with Ice Lake

Comment: Yeah both have two jumps, but the rearranged loop does run [really slightly faster](https://pastebin.com/YfMfazvi). Maybe the CPU predicts better when the branch is at the end of the loop rather than within.